# polymer-cli: application and url to reusable components

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I'm trying to start a new project using polymer-cli by following the basic steps to init a project

```
mkdir my-proj
cd my-proj
polymer init
```

Then I add a custom element inside my project

```
cd src
mkdir my-el
touch my-el/my-el.html
```

After adding some sample code in `my-el.html` I start the server and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/components/my-el/` to view the elment documentation and demo but I can't see anything. Just an element not found. 
How to enable the reusable components view in an application using polymer-cli ?